# Grails - are cascades transactional

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

In Grails, do cascades happen within a transaction?

Heres an example from the Grails documentation to demonstrate:

Given the following classes:

```
class Airport {
    String name
    static hasMany = [flights: Flight]
}

class Flight {
    String number
    static belongsTo = [airport: Airport]
}
```

> If I now create an Airport and add some Flights to it I can save the
>   Airport and have the updates cascaded down to each flight, hence
>   saving the whole object graph:

```
new Airport(name: "Gatwick")
        .addToFlights(new Flight(number: "BA3430"))
        .addToFlights(new Flight(number: "EZ0938"))
        .save()
```

Does Grails/Hibernate guarantee this operation to be atomic, even if the code is not wrapped in any transaction?

*Source taken from the example found [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#cascades)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, without using transactions there is no guarantee of atomic operations such as that through GORM or Hibernate.